# Change certain elements in a list to an int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
aList = ['asdf123', '100', '45', '34hello']
```

how can I change it so the '100' and '45' becomes int rather than str?

```
aList = ['asdf123', 100, 45, '34hello']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please show what you have so far. For more information, see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @cricket_007 removed comment about dup

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper function,

```
def to_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return s

aList = [to_int(n) for n in aList]
```

Comment: It's useless to call `int(s)` first time, because it can raise exception in `return` statement.

Comment: At the moment this is the only answer that uses a meaningful and PEP-8 compliant name for the function. Well done.

Comment: aw, shucks, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a method which will convert an integer or return the original value;

```
def tryInt(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except:
        return value
```

Then use `map` and `lambda`;

```
map( lambda x: tryInt(x), aList )
```

Comment: Or list comprehension, `[tryInt(n) for n in aList]`

Answer (score 0):

The following should get your there.

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

aList = map(convert, aList)
```